# Changing shipping methods depending on products in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, shipping-methods

I want to change shipping method depending on products present in the cart.
There are different weights assigned to products.
**If all products present in the cart are of less than 5 k.g (weight for each product) then one shipping method will display.**

**If any one product in the cart, has weight greater than 5 kg. then show another shipping method.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `collectRates` method from the 2 methods you need and add this.
for the one that is allowed only if all the products are below 5kg:

```
$items = $request->getAllItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getWeight() > 5) {
         return false;
    }
}
```

and for the one that is allowed only if there is a product with weight over 5:

```
$items = $request->getAllItems();
$allowed = false;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getWeight() > 5) {
         $allowed = true;
         break;
    }
}
if (!$allowed) {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. But I am planning to do it via observer.. Is it right to do via observer? If yes which observer should I use? so that it will enable disable method on checkout.

Comment: I don't know any event for the shipping methods...I'll post one if I find it.

Comment: can you please tell me can I use your logic for Table Rates shipping method? Then I will override Flatrate.php and Tablerate.php.

Comment: override Tablerate.php

Comment: Really thank you for your guide.. now can you suggest some links for override Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate. So that I can add new code. Sorry but I am a newbie in magento.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/

Comment: <global>
       <models>
          <shipping>
            <carrier>
              <rewrite>
                  <flatrate>Emqube_Mymodule_Model_Carrier_Flatrate</flatrate>
              </rewrite>
            </carrier>
          </shipping>
       </models>
    </global>
I have added this in my modules config file, and your code in newly overriden file but flatrate method is still displaying.